# Cordova AppRate Plugin usesUntilPrompt not working

Tags: cordova, plugins

I am using cordova app-rate plugin but my App doesn't seem to obey the useUntilPrompt preference. I have set this to 3 but it displays the popup on every load. I have tried with promtForRating(true), promtForRating(false) and promtForRating(). None of them have the desired outcome which is to only display the popup after 3 loads of the app.

Has anyone had success with this plugin and the useUntilPrompt preference?

```
AppRate.preferences.storeAppURL.ios = 'xxxx';
AppRate.preferences.usesUntilPrompt = 3;
AppRate.promptForRating();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the API has been changed in the latest version. You have to call:

> AppRate.promptForRating(false)

Then, `usesUntilPrompt` counter will be considered it seems. Check out this [link](https://github.com/pushandplay/cordova-plugin-apprate/issues/122) for more info on the same.